# Simple equation with square root $2x-6-4\sqrt x=0$

Tags: radicals

Good evening to everybody,
I have a doubt about the following simple equation:

$$2x-6-4\sqrt x=0$$

I know that x should equal to $9$.

But how do I arrive to this result? In particular, my difficulty is to deal with square root.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to "isolate" the square root in one side of your equation

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Let $\sqrt x = t\ge 0$ then we have

$$2x-6-4\sqrt x=0 \iff 2t^2-4t-6=0$$

then solve the quadratic equation and then select the solutions $t\ge 0$.

Comment: I suppose you can also divide out a factor of $2$.

Comment: Yes of course, it might help a little bit too!

Answer (score 2):

$x>0.$

$x-3-2\sqrt x=0.$

$(√x+1)(√x -3)=0$.

The only solution is $√x=3$ (why?).